# how to insert a caption to a table in c# with office.interop.word library

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, desktop-application

Hello to whoever that may read  this Im working my way to become a C# developer. The first project assigned to me is writing a word document report automation (and extend it to the main app) i Find the office.interop.word library documentation from Microsoft docs rather intimidating.

so theres a **CaptionLabels** *Interface*  and it has an **Add** method yet i dont know how to
assign the created caption to the purposed Table and  heres my code :

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            //Start Word and create a new document.
            Word._Application oWord;
            Word._Document oDoc;
            oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            Object oTemplate = "C:\\Users\\a_shiGenerate word document report\\acidproTemplateDocx.docx";
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
          //some code in between here

            oWord.CaptionLabels.Add("some caption");
            object caption = oWord.CaptionLabels["some caption"];
            oWord.Selection.InsertCaption(ref caption, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref Tables[3], ref oMissing);
            /* in the line above Tables[3] is an unaccepted value but how to add this caption to this (any) particular table */
            oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 5, 10, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oDoc.Paragraphs.SpaceBefore = 0.0f;
            oDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 25.0f;
            oDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 29.0f;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Columns[2].Cells.PreferredWidth = 100;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Columns[1].Cells.PreferredWidth = 100;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "hello";
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "arman";
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "this";
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "is  Image";
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 3).Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Cell(1, 4).Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Range.Font.Size = 10;
            oDoc.Tables[3].Rows.Height = 2.0f;
```

so how can i assign captions to a certain table ?

any help/tips/howtos on working with this library would be much appreciated (the whole web has been searched and no useful reference found ).

Comment: Where are the variables `wrdRng` and `Tables` defined? From a guessing state… I am betting that the caption is getting set properly in the document… but it is getting overwritten when the table is inserted with `oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 5, 10, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);` … a simple trace should validate this. Again I am guessing what the value of `wrdRng` is. Lastly, if you can use a third-party library instead of “interop”… I suggest you do so now.

Comment: `wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
            wrdRng.InsertAfter("THE END.");`     theyre defined  here  thanks for your tip im afraid cant change the library could u be a bit more specific on how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, still guessing, since you still did not define `Tables`… in my tests… that code will put the “Caption” as the FIRST paragraph in the document and the table as the last paragraph in the doc. However, the “caption” does appear to be assigned and is displayed as the first paragraph in the document. I am guessing you may want to move the caption down to the bottom of the doc where the table is.

If this is the case, then try the code below…

```
// set the range to the end of the document
wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
wrdRng.InsertAfter("THE END.");
// insert the caption below “The End”…
oWord.CaptionLabels.Add("some caption");
object caption = oWord.CaptionLabels["some caption"];
wrdRng.InsertCaption(ref caption, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
// insert the table after the caption…
wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 5, 10, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Lastly, I highly recommend you put all the code that works with the Word Doc into a `try/catch/finally` statement to ensure all the COM objects your code creates get disposed of properly. Something like…

```
try {
   // all the code that works with the Word doc
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  // message box error ex.Message
}
finally {
   if (oDoc != null) {
      oDoc.Save();
      oDoc.Close();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oDoc);
    }

    if (oWord != null) {
      oWord.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much my friend you taught me a lot in one post !